# Why can <script> not be added directly into the .html() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

I am learning front end dev and built my own version of JS Bin. Upon clicking the 'run' button this statement is executed to display the html, css and js in an iframe (the output window):

```
("iframe").contents().find("html").html("<style>"+$("#cssCode").val()+"</style>"+$("#htmlCode").val()+"<script>"+$("#jsCode").val()+"</script>");
```

I understand that you cannot add the  statement into this .html() function - it does not execute the js. However I do not understand why. Does anyone know?

Comment: `"<\/script>"` you have to escape the closing slash and read about same origin policy.

Comment: @Jai thanks i did escape the closing slash. it did fix some issues but that still didn't allow the code to run. what do you mean by same origin policy?

Comment: You really dont need an `iframe` for this. You can use any block level element as the output container.

Comment: @SunilJindal Same origin policy means you can access elements of iframe if that document is also running on same url and port.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I'm a newbie! That's how it was done in the course I'm using to learn

Answer (score 0):

To understand this error correctly, consider the following code:

```
<body>
  <script>
    var html = 'The script tag will ended with </script>';
    document.body.innerHTML = html
  </script>
</body>
```

The rendering engine will start parsing the HTML document and convert elements to DOM nodes in a tree called the **`content tree`**; And the result will be as follows:

```
<body>
  <script>var html = 'The script tag will ended with</script>
  '; document.body.innerHTML = html
</body>
```

And in this case, when the `JavaScript` engine starts executing this code, It returns `SyntaxError: unterminated string literal`. Because the string literals must be enclosed by single `(')` or double `(")` quotes.

### So, what is the solution?

The quick solution is to use a `"&lt;"` instead of `"<"`. Like the below code:

```html
<script>
  var html = 'The script tag will ended with &lt;/script>';
  document.body.innerHTML = html
</script>
```

### How to executing "script" elements inserted with ".innerHTML"?

In the below example, we want to put the jQuery library with the innerHTML function in the document and execute it:

```js
var html = '&lt;script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">&lt;/script>',
    el = document.getElementById( 'test' );

el.innerHTML = html;

var str = el.innerHTML.split(/"/)[1],
    tag = document.createElement( 'script' );

tag.src = str;
document.getElementsByTagName( 'head' )[ 0 ].appendChild( tag )
```

```html
<button onclick="$('#test').html('The script inserted and loaded.')">Execute</button>
<div id="test"></div>
```